# calling .DLL file through java

Tags: java, dll

I have a DLL file mostly written in vb.net
It will take 2 parameters.
I am suppose to make use of this DLL in my java code and pass required 2 parameters.
How should I go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling C++ dll from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9485896/calling-c-dll-from-java) & [Calling .NET DLL from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8477752/calling-net-dll-from-java)

Answer (score 3):

Use [JNI](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/), Load your dll and call native functions

**See**

- [Examples](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/jniexamp.html)

Answer (score 3):

In Java there's basically two good options for this: (in order of recommendation)

1. If your DLL has C function headers (rather than C++ decorations), you should use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna/). It has a simple, [declarative syntax](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/DirectMapping.md) and only requires writing some Java.
2. Write JNI bindings for your DLL (there'll be some Java and some C++ code involved).

Comment: Hi Mark, as I stated in my first post, DLL is a pure vb.net code. So I should go abt having JNI. Any samples you have to know wat exactly needs to be done in C++